# I'm on vacation in Vienna and was never asked to stamp my passport, what do I do?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, europe, passport-stamps

I'm a Canadian but I'm on vacation in the Netherlands and Austria. Today I had the flight from Amsterdam to Vienna and after I had checked my bags I just was able to walk through as I had nothing to claim.

I never stamped my passport or went through any customs office. I think I might have accidentally went through the EU resident area, but there was still no check.

I remember that when I landed in the Netherlands there was an area to check passport for EU citizens, so I'm confused as to why there wasn't one in Vienna. I'm going back to Canada in five days and I'm afraid that I'll get denied or banned or something, what do I do here?

Comment: It can actually be complicated to get a stamp in the Schengen area. I needed that once and had to pace the airport back and forth to find someone who would do it (this looked weird to them but I had a good reason)

Comment: Netherlands-Austria is by all intents a **domestic** route in the Schengen Area. You are Canadian, so you should be familiar with US travels where you can travel across *states* without stamping your passport

Answer (score 53):

The Netherlands and Austria are in the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area). There are no border checks (unless exceptional circumstances) and no immigration stamps. You will receive the stamp when you leave the Schengen area.

Comment: The airtravel tab on the Schengen wikipedia page explains that border controls don't usually happen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Air_travel

Comment: Even if there is a border check on a Schengen internal border or a Schengen internal flight, there will be no stamp.  The stamps record entry into and departure from Schengen.  There is no stamp for an internal border crossing.

Answer (score 17):

The countries in the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) operate in many ways as if they are one country.  For example, if you had needed a visa for these countries then the visa from one would be valid for the other (*).  What you did is similar to a trip that I may make soon.  I will fly London to Toronto Ontario, fly to Montreal Quebec, and finally back to London.  I don't expect to get my passport checked and stamped between Toronto and Montreal.

(*) There are some factors not relevant to you e.g. if the main purpose of your trip is in one country then you should apply to that country and not attempt to shop around.

Comment: You example is not valid as Toronto and Montreal are the same country but Amsterdam and Vienna are different country.

Comment: @vasin1987 _"operate in many ways as if they are one country"_ The point of the answer is that Schengen turns an international transit into the equivalent of a transit between subnational entities (like between the provinces of Ontario and Quebec). -- Perhaps you'd prefer the analogy to be London to Glasgow. Technically different countries (England vs. Scotland), but for all intents and purposes equivalent to a single country (UK internal) trip.

Comment: @vasin1987 I intended it as R.M. says.  Travelling between Schrngen countries is now similar to travelling between subnational units of other countries.  If you travel by land you may just see a "Welcome to ..." sign at the border rather like crossing to another county within a country.  R.M. gave another example.  A third would be New York to Los Angeles.

Comment: On a minor point, I'll probably take a train from Toronto to Montreal.

Comment: @njzk2 Look at my last comment.  I slightly distorted my plan to make it more analogous to the OP's.

Comment: good to hear, cheers!

Comment: There are two Londons with flights to Toronto Ontario.  Did you mean [London International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_International_Airport), London Heathrow Airport, or London Gatwick Airport?

Comment: @R.M. On the other hand, Québec operates in many ways as if it's _not_ in the same country as the rest of Canada.  For example, its provincial parks are called Parc National

Comment: @gerrit One of the UK ones.

Comment: @gerrit We have the same problem in the EU.  Worse, 24 official languages not just 2.